Delete Image from TabView Using SwiftData & Updating the UI
I'm using SwiftUI to create a simple app listing "Places I've Been". There is a DetailView with a single Place (one) that can have many PlaceImages (many) associated with it. Here are the two models
@Model
class PlaceImage {
    var date = Date.now
    @Attribute(.externalStorage) var image: Data? = nil
    
    init(date: Foundation.Date = Date.now, image: Data? = nil) {
        self.date = date
        self.image = image
    }
    
    // added this to relate back
    var place: Place?
}
@Model
class Place {
    var city: String
    var country: String
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)
    var imageArray: [PlaceImage] = []
    init(city: String, imageArray: [PlaceImage] = [], country: String) {
        self.city = city
        self.imageArray = imageArray
        self.country = country
    }
}

The images are shown in a swipeable TabView. The UI is simple just so I can get things working. I load the image, date/time (for debugging), and a delete button. When the delete button is pressed, I find the displayed image in the array of images using the unique date/time. Then I .delete from the modelContext at the imageArray's index value. When inspecting in real-time with DB Browser, this seems to delete the image from the Many file (PlaceImage), but the element isn't eliminated from the array, nor is the TabView updated. I had suspected this would work like deleting from the modelContext in a list view, where the list data updates automatically. Am I doing this properly & just need to also delete the element from the image: place.imageArray.remove(at: index), or am I going about this the wrong way? And if I need to manually delete from the array to update the UI (which seems to work), why do I need to do that in PageView, but not in a ListView where .delete() seems to handle the UI update automatically.
import SwiftData
import PhotosUI
struct DetailView: View {
@State var place: Place
@State var city = ""
@State var country = ""
@State private var selection: PhotoSelection = PhotoSelection()
@Environment(.dismiss) private var dismiss
@Environment(.modelContext) var modelContext
struct PhotoSelection: Hashable {
    var photoItem: PhotosPickerItem?
    var image: UIImage?
}

var body: some View {
    VStack (alignment: .leading) {
        Text("City:")
            .bold()
        TextField("Enter a city", text: $city)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            .padding(.bottom)
        
        Text("Country:")
            .bold()
        TextField("Enter a country", text: $country)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        
        TabView {
            ForEach(place.imageArray, id: \.self) { placeImage in
                VStack {
                    if let imageData = placeImage.image, let uiimage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                        Image(uiImage: uiimage)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                    }
                    Text("\(placeImage.date)")
                    Button("Delete") {
                        print("You clicked in image \(placeImage.date)")
                        if let index = place.imageArray.firstIndex(where: {$0.date == placeImage.date}) {
                            modelContext.delete(place.imageArray[index])
                            // place.imageArray.remove(at: index) // seems to work if this is uncommented
                            print("No of images after delete: \(place.imageArray.count)")
                        }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                    .tint(.red)
                }
            }
        } .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
        
        HStack (alignment: .center) {
            PhotosPicker(selection: $selection.photoItem, matching: .images, photoLibrary: .shared()) {
                Label("Add Photo", systemImage: "photo")
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        
        Spacer()
    }
    .onChange(of: selection) { oldValue, newValue in
        handleSelectedPhotoItem()
    }
    .onAppear {
        city = place.city
        country = place.country
    }
    .font(.title2)
    .padding()
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
            Button("Cancel") {
                //Action
                dismiss()
            }
        }
        ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
            Button("Save") {
                //Action
                place.city = city
                place.country = country
                modelContext.insert(place)
                dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}

private func saveImage(with imageData: Data) {
    let placeImage = PlaceImage(date: .now, image: imageData)
    place.imageArray.append(placeImage)
    modelContext.insert(place)
}

private func handleSelectedPhotoItem() {
    if let selectedPhotoItem = selection.photoItem {
        selectedPhotoItem.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) {result in
            switch result {
            case .success (let data):
                if let imageData = data {
                    saveImage(with: imageData)
                    selection = PhotoSelection()
                }
            case .failure (let error):
                print(" ERROR: Error loading photo item \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}

}
And here is what the basic View looks like w/other fields:


To improve your chances of getting help you should ask one clearly formulated  question.

you've got a memory leak of UImages being init in body, it would be best for you to lazy load that in the model class and hang onto it in there.

You're showing only the code for TabView. You should include the complete struct so we can see how everything is defined.

Updated at request of @AndreiG. above.

I am not sure the code is complete. For example, where is ForEach(place...) defined? That body is missing its struct maybe.

Observations, in your DetailView, you probably should declare var place: Place
or @Bindable var place: Place.
Also use ForEach(place.imageArray), no id: \.self.
In your Button("Delete") try using id such as,
if let index = place.imageArray.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == placeImage.id}).
You could also try using place.city and place.country directly (when using @Bindable var place: Place), instead of using
intermediate @State var city and country which don't seem to do anything.
